# How to delete values from selected list 3 by 3 from bottom of the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery & I have a problem with my code. I couldn't remove the selected values from list box.

i.e Firstly, I select any three values from the first three boxes, Then i click "Add Category". So, The selected three values will be in the forth box. Again, I select any three values from the first three boxes and I click "Add Category" button. So, Totally 6 values will be there in fourth box. Now, When i click(first click) "Remove Category" button, The last three values should be deleted from bottom and on next click, again three values should be deleted. Likewise, I want reduce the values 3 by 3 on every click.

```js
var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
$('#add-category').click(function() {
  $(
    '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
  ).each(function() {
    $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
  });
});
$('#remove-category').click(function() {
  $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').each(function() {
    var the_index = $(this).val() - 1;
    $('#selected-lst-values')
      .find('option:nth-last-of-type(' + the_index + ')')
      .remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select></div>

<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select></div>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$('#remove-category').click(function() {// check change here
   var select = document.getElementById('selected-lst-values');

   for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
       select.removeChild(select.lastChild);
   }
});
```

Example:-

```js
var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
$('#add-category').click(function() {
  $(
    '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
  ).each(function() {
    $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
  });
});
$('#remove-category').click(function() {// check change here
  var select = document.getElementById('selected-lst-values');
  
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
      select.removeChild(select.lastChild);
    }
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select></div>

<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select></div>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: @Alukkupaiyan  glad to help you.:)

Answer (score 1):

See this.

Just added a `for` loop.

Also i don't understand why you are using `.find('option:nth-last-of-type(' + the_index + ')')` in your code. This will not work because `the_index` is not actually the index value but the value in the field.

Instead i used `.children().last()`

```js
var one = $('.select-manage-category').val();
var two = $('.select-manage-category1').val();
var three = $('.select-manage-category2').val();
$('#add-category').click(function() {
  $(
    '.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2'
  ).each(function() {
    $('#selected-lst-values').append('<option value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
  });
});
$('#remove-category').click(function() {
  $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').each(function() {
    //console.log($('#selected-lst-values').children());
    var the_index = $('#selected-lst-values').length - 1;
    for(var i=0; i<=3 && the_index>=0; i++,the_index--){
      $('#selected-lst-values').children().last()
      .remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select></div>

<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p class="text-center color-red">You can add up to 20 categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="5">
  </select></div>
<button class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save</strong> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the same from bottom? i.e I want to remove from last three values that i selected.

Comment: @Alukkupaiyan I made the change in the answer. Now last three entries will be removed instead of first three